# AutoHotKey - repeating if statement keeps treating its condition as true in a loop

Tags: loops, if-statement, autohotkey

I'm trying to create an autoclicker using AutoHotKey for a game which has a system for fishing. This system makes an icon of a black exclamation mark surrounded by a large square border of white appear above your head, at which point you have to spam left click to catch the fish. Since the time at which the icon appears is randomly different each time, I have to be able to determine the time at which to spam click dynamically.

I've attempted to do that using PixelGetColor(as shown below) to find a particular pixel which ends up white whenever the exclamation mark appears, yet it never detects the exclamation mark, and more concerningly, whenever it detects the particular pixel on my screen to be white, the if statement's condition following PixelGetColor always returns true.

```
Toggle = False

loop 
{
  if (Toggle = "true")
  { 
    Sleep, 100
    PixelGetColor, color, 966, 463
    if (color = 0xFFFFFFFF) {
          MsgBox, It works!
    }
  }
}

F1::
if (Toggle = "true") {
  Toggle = False
}
else {
  Toggle = True
}
```

F1 is bound to a boolean which determines if the code inside of the loop is ran or not. The last two inputs for PixelGetColor, 966 and 463, are the x and y positions of the specific pixel respectively.

I'm expecting to get different values for the color once I start moving my camera in game, but after it detects white it proceeds to spam the message about the script 'working' when it clearly doesn't.

Simply put, what the hell is going on? I've been trying to figure that out for a while now. If anyone could give an explanation of what I've done wrong, as well as a snippet of code for what *should* be done inside of the loop to make the program work as intended, I would be eternally(well, almost) grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code as is, I don't get the message box after pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>. (I ensured the pixel at the specified coordinates was white.) Changing the color match to "0xFFFFFF" (two bytes per RGB) made it work for me and it worked as you intended in your description.

However, I am surprised it worked because true/false is being stored as a string in variable `Toggle` and I fully expected "True" wouldn't match "true" because of the case difference. (After a little more digging, I found that `=` in expressions is case-insensitive; `==` is case-sensitive - I guess I learned something today.)

Other than the color, I saw nothing in the code that would prevent it from working. Below is a modified version of yours that treats true/false as boolean values and is simplified slightly. Hopefully it will work for you too.

```
Loop 
{
    If Toggle
    { 
        Sleep , 100
        PixelGetColor , color , 966 , 463
        If ( color = 0xFFFFFF )
            MsgBox ,,, It works! , 0.5
}   }

f1::Toggle := !Toggle
```

---

**Edit:** *Added area and variance to search per comment below.*
Replace the two `PixelGetColor` and the `If` statement lines with the two lines below.

```
        PixelSearch ,,, 900 , 400 , 1000 , 500 , 0xFFFFFF , 20 , FastRGB
        If !ErrorLevel
```

This will search a 100x100px area for pure white with 20 shades of variance. You may need to adjust the rectangle size and placement as well as the variance to get it to work for you. More info [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PixelSearch.htm).

Comment: This script is working perfectly, on everything *but* the game. See, I've tested the script on a chrome window, looking for a perfectly white background(on this page in fact), and the script worked exactly as intended. However, I realized that the icon started fading from the moment it appeared, and that it additionally also was somewhat random in its placement above the avatar's  head, so I would like to ask another question, and I would prefer that you edited your answer: How would I look for white to near-white colors in a specific *area* on the screen?

Comment: Again; the script is fine when detecting the white background of this page, yet it can't seem to detect white in the game, despite me basically aiming at(the over-bloomed) sun, which was essentially a giant white ball in the sky. I believe that the real issue may be more deeply rooted in the inner workings of how pixel memory is stored; it may be that PixelSearch was simply unnecessary to achieve what I'm attempting to, and that I could've just stuck with PixelGetColor. Either way, I'm going to keep looking for the exact problem, and would be grateful if you maybe did a little digging as well.

Comment: ignore my previous comment, this was a typographical error on myself. I forgot the 'MsgBox ,,, It works! , 0.5' line of the code, a stupid mistake. Anyhow, the program is detecting the icon! It does exactly as intended now. Thank you for your help, and I'll mark your question as correct.